# Генерация простых чисел с заданными свойствами

Tags: математика, криптография, алгоритм

Для реализации криптографического алгоритма необходимо сгенерировать достаточно большие простые числа p и q такие, что каждое из них сравнимо с 3 по модулю 4. Изучая методы генерации простых чисел, я счел подходящим для себя метод, основанный на [тесте Миллера-Рабина](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тест_Миллера_—_Рабина). Общая идея такова: берется достаточно большое число, проверяется тестом, если тест показывает "число вероятно простое" - берем его, иначе - прибавляем к нему 1 и снова проверяем тестом. Как модифицировать этот алгоритм, чтобы (с некоторой вероятностью) получать простые числа заданной длины с описанным выше свойством?

Comment: @DarkGenius что такое:

> сравнимо с 3 по модулю 4

то есть, имеется 3-е число с которым они сравнимы по модулю 4?

Comment: То есть число дает остаток 3 при делении на 4.

Comment: Необходимо код написать? Или построить самый оптимальный алгоритм?

Спрашиваю, так как решение мне показалось элементарным и не требующим вопросов. Каждое число, прошедшее через тест Миллера-Рабина, проверяем на два условия:

- Число дает остаток 3 при делении на 4
- Число больше заданной границы

Если вышеописанные условия удовлетворены, тогда продолжаем работу с этим числом.

Возможно, Я про100 неправильно понял задачу. В таком случае прошу меня извинить.

Comment: Да, в целом вы поняли правильно. Для полного ответа только необходимо указать как выбрать стартовое число и как переходить к очередному числу. 
Я решил задачу так (код на Python, rmspp - тест Миллера Рабина):

Comment: что бы числа удоволетворяли Вашим условиям (то есть, при делении на 4 давали 3 в остатке и при этом были простыми), нужно тестить числа вида 12n+7 и 12n+11. Все остальные будут гарантированно либо составными, либо не давать нужного остатка (ну кроме собственно числа 3).

Поэтому быстрый переход по таким числам +4 + 8 попеременно.

Comment: @KoVadim, как это доказывается?

Comment: очень легко. представим все числа в виде 12n+a, n - целое, больше 0, a = 0..11. Легко доказать, что числа вида 12n+0, 12n+2, ... 12n+10 будут делиться на два (это просто парные числа). числа вида 12n+3 , 12n+6, 12n+9 будут делиться на 3. Поэтому остаются 12n+1, 12n+5, 12n+7, 12n+11.
Вывод - любое простое, больше 12 при делении на 12 даст в остатке 1,5,7 или 11. Других вариантов не может быть. так как 12 при делении на 4 даст остаток 0, то проверяем только вторую часть. 7 и 11 - два возможных варианта.

Поэтому, генерируем любое число, умножаем на 12 и прибавляем 7. Первое почти простое готово

Comment: В моем коде выше была ошибка. Исправлюсь: http://pastebin.com/k7h5Aq8q